# When the ass is feeling too good, it goes dancing on ice

Tags: expressions

This is the literal English equivalent of the German proverb

> Wenn es dem Esel zu wohl ist, geht er aufs Eis tanzen

The proverb commonly describes the behaviour of people who are comfortably well-off and perhaps somewhat complacent, so they seek a little excitement in their lives by doing reckless things.

The expression was used by some posters in German forums to characterize the government's decision in 2015 to allow large numbers of migrants to enter the country.

Currently I have seen the expression used a couple of times to explain the significantly increased popularity of the Green party in Bavaria, which is the richest region of Germany and traditionally very conservative.

I have not been able to find a good English equivalent. Does anyone know of a figurative expression for complacent people who indulge in foolish behaviour in order to spice up their lives a little?

Comment: We talk about people "having more money than sense" - which I suppose is related, but not quite the same thing.

Comment: "while the cat's away, the mice will play" is similar, but perhaps not exactly the same.

Comment: I've seen a lot of film noir exchanges where someone repeats one or another variation of, "When a guy gets too comfortable, he gets careless."

Comment: NB The animal is called a donkey in everyday speech. 'Ass' fell out of use about 200 years ago because 'refined' people thought it sounded too much like 'arse' (US 'ass').

Comment: @Kate Bunting. You are right that _ass_ is relatively uncommon in modern usage. I used it partly because it is cognate with the German word, and partly (shameful I know) because I thought it may garner more views than _donkey_. Its double meaning makes me think that the expression used about loquacious people should be: _She can talk the hind legs off an ass_.

Comment: Nothing shameful about creating an eye-catching title, although I actually thought it meant someone dancing on ice with their buttocks.  It's possible!

Comment: "(rich) fools rush in where angels fear to tread"?

Comment: This falls into the category of "rich people's problems". But I don't know anything  with similar imagery. The Stones wanted you to "get yer [ya-ya's](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=get%20your%20ya-ya%27s%20out#) out" in 1970, but that's a while back now.

Comment: People seeking excitement want to *spice up their lives*. But that's not specific to the rich.